# Words similar to "undervalue(verb)" or "underestimate"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that means something like "to think of as less important" such as in the following sentence:

> Theory is more important than practice; of course, this is not to completely *'word'* the value of practice.

So far I found "belittle", "depreciate" and "discredit", but they don't work in the previous sentence. I'm looking for a word that is not too hard as in "vilify". Something that means "think of as less important" or "think of as insignificant".

Comment: floccinaucinihilipilificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Theory is more important than practice; of course, this is not to completely *[understate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/understate)* the value of practice.

Answer (score 2):

I really like **downplay** there.

> down·play ˈdounˌplā/ verb verb: downplay; 3rd person present:
>   downplays; past tense: downplayed; past participle: downplayed; gerund
>   or present participle: downplaying
>
> ```
> 1.
> make (something) appear less important than it really is.
> "this report downplays the seriousness of global warming"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There's also *discount*:

> to think of (something) as having little importance or value

or *dismiss*:

> to reject serious consideration of

Answer (score 0):

*to lessen*:

can also be an alternative to convey the idea of something that may be consider of less of inferior value.

... this is not to completely **lessen the value of practice**

Answer (score 0):

Theory is more important than practice; of course, this is not to completely { **devalue**, **denigrate**, **deny**,...} the value of practice.

(But really such questions should be *closed* -- consult a thesaurus.)